# How do I access the component object of the child components I render in a list?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, dynamic

I have a JSON payload with a service in my component, but then I'm not sure how would I obtain a reference to the list items component objects from the parent component.

Comment: Respectfully, this question indicates that you do not really understand how Angular works: I recommend you to read angular.io through and learn the basic concepts. Using Angular means you use the tools recommended by the Angular team: directly manipulating the DOM WILL cause errors and unpredictable sideeffects.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: I'm still figuring it... so in no way I am allowed to change the DOM inside my component and must have the template ready ahead of time, right?

Comment: I recommend that you look up how Angular Change Detecion works, what is the purpose of Zone.js, and how Angular enables you to DO manipulate the DOM, but not directly you see... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0o-4yc2n-8

Comment: Thanks, this is a very informative talk!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ngFor loop.

```
 {
  "data": [
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": " Name1"
      },
      {
        "id": "21",
        "name": " Name2"
      },
      {
        "id": "24",
        "name": " Name3"
      },
      {
        "id": "11",
        "name": " Name4"
      }
  ]
}
```

In HTML Code

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let item of data" 
    [value]="item.id" >
  {{item.name}}
</option>
</select>
```